# How could I update a Datatable in modal using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-datatables

I have been stuck in something simple that I think I haven't solved yet because of a lack of experience. Here is the catch I have a very simple controller which load the data from a service when I first Load the modal but once I tried to use the CRUD operations (hopefully working!!) the datatable doesn't update. I will share the code. Thanks of all.

I need that after insert, for example, the datatable update meaning rerender the current list of elements.

**Call of the Modal**

```
vm.openBooksModal = function (authorId) {
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: '/app/book/index.html,
            controller: 'BooksController',                
            size: '',
            resolve: {
                authorId: function () {
                    return authorId;
                }
            }
        });
```

**Modal Controller**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
     angular.module('bookApp').controller('BooksController',  BooksController);

    BooksController.$inject = ['$uibModalInstance', '$scope', 'authorId', 'bookService', 'DTOptionsBuilder', 'DTColumnDefBuilder',
    'DTColumnBuilder', 'dtUtils','alertService'];

function NotesController($uibModalInstance, $scope, authorId, bookService, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnDefBuilder,
    DTColumnBuilder, dtUtils, alertService) {

    $scope.authorId= authorId;

    $scope.book= { 
        id: 0,
        title:''
    };


    //if (angular.isDefined())      

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    }

    $scope.dtBooksColumnDefs = [
        DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(0).notSortable()
    ];

    $scope.dtBooksOptions = DTOptionsBuilder          
        .newOptions()
        .withOption('bFilter', false)
        .withOption('order', [[2, 'desc']])            
        .withOption('aaSorting', [])
        .withOption('lengthMenu', [[5, 10, 25, 50], [5, 10, 25, 50]]);


    $scope.dtBooksInstance = {};
    $scope.LoadData = LoadData();

    function LoadData(){
       return bookService.getBook($scope.authorId).$promise
        .then(getBookCompleted, handleError);
    }

     $scope.save = function (newTitle) { 
        $scope.book.title= newTitle;
        bookService.saveBook($scope.book.id, $scope.authorId, $scope.book.title).$promise
            .then(saveBookCompleted, handleError); 

        LoadData();
    }

    $scope.editBook= function( book){

        $scope.book= book;
        $scope.newTitle= book.title;
    }

    $scope.deleteBook = function( book){
         bookService.deleteBook(book.id).$promise
                     .then(saveBookCompleted, handleError);     

    }

    //private methods
    function getBookCompleted(data) {            
        $scope.leadBookList = data; 
        debugger; 
        if (angular.isDefined($scope.dtBookInstance.rerender)) {
            $scope.dtBooksInstance.rerender();                
        }

          $scope.book= { };
          $scope.newTitle = '';  
    }

    function saveBookCompleted() {
        bookService.getBook($scope.authorId).$promise
            .then(getBookCompleted, handleError);
    }

    function handleError(response) {
        alertService.error("Error trying to add a Note. Please try again later or contact IT.");
    }

}
})();
```

**HTML TEMPLATE**

```
   <div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">Books</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="book-container">
        <div class="head">
        </div>
        <div class="book">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <label class="control-label">{{headerLabel}}</label>
                        <textarea id="newTitle" class="comment-textarea" data-ng-model="newTitle" rows="8" cols="90"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">                   
                    <table id="tblBooks" datatable="ng" class="table table-striped table-bordered font-xs" 
                           dt-options="dtBookOptions" dt-column-defs="dtBookColumnDefs" >
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th></th> 
                                <th></th> 
                                <th>Title</th>
                                <th>Created By</th>
                                <th>Created Date</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr data-ng-repeat="book in BookList">
                                 <td>

                                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning"  ng-click="editBook(book)">
                                        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                                    </button>
                                  </td>
                                  <td>
                                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"   ng-click="deleteBook(book)">
                                        <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                                    </button>

                                </td>
                                <td>{{book.title}}</td>
                                <td>{{book.createdBy}}</td>
                                <td>{{book.createdDate | date:'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss'}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
       </div>
    <div class="modal-footer margin-top-0">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="save(newBook)" data-ng-disabled="newTitle === ''">Save</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="cancel()">Close</button>
    </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Would you mind to show template also?

Comment: Thanks, I already did it!

Comment: So when you are updating the data in model the same is not updating in your datatable?

Comment: That is exactly what is happening.

Comment: Can you also explain the series of events. I guess you have a datatable. 1. click on icon -> 2. opens a modal -> 3. update data in modal 4. close modal

Comment: 1. Basic Table with a set of data and an icon which call the modal using vm.openBooksModal.
2. All other is part of the modal and I just want handle the datatable CRUD in the same modal.
All without closing the modal

Comment: So the issue is you are performing CRUD but the data is not updating in the model ?

Comment: The model is completly fine, no issues.The problem is when I try to either rerender or reload the datatable

Comment: Where you are rerendering Datatable?

Comment: if (angular.isDefined($scope.dtBookInstance.rerender)) {
            $scope.dtBooksInstance.rerender();                
        }

This if always has value false, so never rerender.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling getBookCompleted twice. First after save in the saveBookCompleted function and second in the loaddata function

```
$scope.save = function (newTitle) { 
        $scope.book.title= newTitle;
        bookService.saveBook($scope.book.id, $scope.authorId, $scope.book.title).$promise
            .then(saveBookCompleted, handleError); 

        // remove this line since you're already call saveBookCompleted
        //LoadData();
    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135514/discussion-on-answer-by-digit-how-could-i-update-a-datatable-in-modal-using-angu).